# Scraping longitude and latitude of a city from Google Maps

Tags: python, selenium

I want to extract Latitude and Longitude for a city from Google Maps. The flow should go like this

opening google maps URL
Search for a city say 'New York'

Now I want to fetch the Latitude and Longitude of this city. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Where is latitude and longitude mention in that maps ?

Comment: If you do a right-click into the map, you'll see long and lat. To do a click maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807258/selenium-click-at-certain-position

Comment: You can get lat/lon from name of city using [Python Geocoders module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686001/python-module-for-getting-latitude-and-longitude-from-the-name-of-a-us-city)

Comment: @cruisepandey that's the point. They aren't visible straight away. When you right-click a location, you can see the coordinates.

Comment: @DarrylG is there a way to do the same using selenium webdriver module?

Comment: @crushed_bug : Yeah I figured that out, check out the below solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could do it with `context_click` in selenium.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "searchboxinput"))).send_keys("New York")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "searchbox-searchbutton"))).click()
sleep(5)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body")).context_click().perform()
print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul[role='menu']>li div div[class*='text']:nth-of-type(1)"))).text)
```

**O/P:**

> 40.69715, -74.25987

**Don't forget to import these :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank You, brother. That certainly solves my problem. Your URL suggestion was good too. I will try to work on that one as well to have a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

After exploring google maps and how a regular person would find the longitude and latitude i noticed the URL has the longitude and latitude within it so i would search for the location then pull the URL using `driver.current_url` or something like that(not familiar with python) then set it to a variable and use what ever function to trim it down and separate it so you only have the longitude and latitude in 2 separate variables. sorry this only breaks down the process rather then giving you a straight answer, if you have any other questions I would prefer you ask me here. https://discord.gg/fjNX5MuTVq